# Understanding MatLab array cropping and operators from a C# developer's point of view: e.g. data(1:4:end,:,:);

Tags: c#, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am trying to recreate a MatLab script in .NET. The specific piece of code I am looking at is this:

```
raw = fread(fid, [160*4 304*304], 'float32');
% read in raw
data = reshape(raw, [160*4 304 304]);
% reshape matrix into 3D
data = data(end:-1:1,:,:); % To rotate the data into orientation in accordance to Matlab common use
resampledData = data(1:4:end,:,:);
```

The lines I am trying to understand are these:

```
data = data(end:-1:1,:,:);            %line 1
resampledData = data(1:4:end,:,:);    %line 2
```

I have read the binary files into 3D float arrays in C# (`float[160, 304, 304]`), but I don't understand what lines 1 and 2 do, nor how to implement the same "resampling" and "rotating" techniques to 3D float arrays in C#. This is despite my research into the `:` operator, `end`, as well as [MatLab matrices and arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is covered by the documentation both in [Matrix Indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) and [Multidimensional Arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = data(end:-1:1,:,:);            %line 1
```

Crops the `data`-array; the `end` keyword simply points to the last element of the axis. Then, there's stepsize and stop: `start:stepsize:stop`
Line one then slices `data` backwards, beginning at the last element `end`, increment by the stepsize (`-1` in this case) and looks at the corresponding element (`end + (-1)`), all the way to the stop element, `1` in your case. `:` by itself means "all".
So, line 1 just reverses the order of the first axis' elements, and restores it as `data`.

```
resampledData = data(1:4:end,:,:);    %line 2
```

Slices your new `data` array (re-saved in `line1`) according to the same rules as above. `1:4:end` according to `start:stepsize:stop` means it looks at the first element, the fifth element, the ninth, and so on, all the way to the last element. All elements in the second and third axes are not altered in any way.

Illustration:

```
>> test=transpose([1:1:20]) %transpose() for illustration purpose, it doesn't 
                            %change the behavior of the slicing operations

array =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20

>> reverse_array =  array(end:-1:1)

reverse_array =

    20
    19
    18
    17
    16
    15
    14
    13
    12
    11
    10
     9
     8
     7
     6
     5
     4
     3
     2
     1

>> every_fourth = reverse_array(1:4:end)

every_fourth =

    20
    16
    12
     8
     4
```

Why not just slice it backwards from the beginning as `(end:-4:1)`?
As you can see, the remainder of the last step (4-4) = 0, which is our of bounds, thus it is discarded. This is a sure way to access the last element or the original (un-reversed) array, whatever the purpose may me.